# Wifi refuses to stay connected, DNS errors

Tags: raspbian, networking, dns, ping

I've been trying to set up two new Pis for about a week now with no success. I have 4 Pis already of the exact same type (RPi 2 Model B). I'm currently trying to get the Realtek 5370 Dongle that comes with the Canakit to work, but I've tried basically every other type of wifi dongle out there too. I've tried different power sources, different outlets, etc and etc. This has all worked perfectly fine on my previous 4 Pis.

The problem is that the 2 new Pis can't maintain a stable connection. They connect to the network just fine, the Pis have an IP. There are even multiple IP addresses in the /etc/resolv.conf file. No errors in dmesg. No errors in /var/log/syslog. However, about every 8 minutes, the Pi cannot resolve any hostnames.

Example workflow: Turn on the Pi. Everything's connected, I can ping 8.8.8.8. If I leave this running, at about ~8 minutes later, I get errors:

```
From <Pi IP> icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

At this point, I can't ping anything. I can't even ping my DNS nameservers -- they give the same error messages. However, I'm still connected to my network, and /etc/resolv.conf still has IPs in it. No matter what I do (ifdown wlan0/ ifup wlan0), I cannot get the name resolving to work during this time period.

About 5 minutes later, I can suddenly ping things again for another 8 minutes. Then the cycle repeats.

What is going on? This is replicated on both of my new Pi's, each of them use the Rasbian Wheezy img, across multiple different power sources, and any wifi dongle (Edimax, Realtek, and so on). Please help, I've been banging my head on the wall for a week on this!

EDIT:
/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
auto wlan0
auto wlan1

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan1

iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="***"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    pairwise=CCMP TKIP
    group=CCMP TKIP
    eap=TTLS
    auth_alg=OPEN
    ca_cert="/etc/ssl/certs/AddTrust_External_Root.pem"
    identity="****"
    password="****"
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPv2"
}
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess which of the many setup you have tried?

Comment: What do you mean by setup? I'm using Raspbian, installed via NOOBs if that's what you're asking.

Comment: How did you setup networking? What is in `/etc/network/interfaces`? Anything else you changed. There are maybe a dozen ways to setup WiFi. (Also what version of Rasbpian.)

Comment: I'll edit my question.

Comment: What you have there looks like the conventional setup, although `iface wlan1 inet manual` should refer to `wlan0`. This should work, although the older configuration did not handle multiple WiFi dongles well. You did not answer which version. Post May 2015 networking setup changed (see http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697). Strictly, if you want to use this you should disable `dhcpcd` on the newer releases, but your use of `dhcp` causes `dhcpcd`  to close. This shoud work, but I would get rid of all mention of `wlan1`. (IMHO the newer setup is better.)

Comment: Thanks, the wlan1 was actually a typo above, it actually says wlan0. So I should just try taking out the lines that say "iface default inet dhcp" and "iface eth0 inet dhcp"? Or should I disable dhcpd?

Comment: Did you check the access point/router you're connected to?

Comment: Yeah, that router is actually a school router that's part of my university network. Thousands of students use it every day with no problem. (Also, I should mention that I've taken my Pi to multiple locations around campus and I have the same issue.)